# Getting Errors Installing Pods

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods, xcode8, cocoapods-1.1.1

I am having an issue with my xcode project that it is not installing any new pods. I installed the same library on another project and it is working there. the terminal give me the following error when I use

> pod install

[image]

I also update my cocoapods to version 1.11.0 but still getting this error.

Does anyone know any solution?

Comment: What do you get when you do `pod --version`? From the error it sounds like you need to update your CocoaPods: `sudo gem install cocoapods`

Comment: you can understand  by the error message, your current version of CocoaPods is 1.10.1, you need to update your pod to 1.10.2 to install GoogleAppMeasurement.

Comment: i had updated my cocoapods but still this is giving the same error and it is doing this for only 1 project. i am downloading the same pod in another project and it is working there.

Comment: Could you type `pod --version` and ensure that its version is correct? You might have downloaded a good version, but it's not the one that you are using: ie it's there, but you are still using the previous one.

Comment: @Larme i had updated the pods but when I use `pod --version`, this is still have the old version of cocoapods. I had updated the cocoapods again and it works. Thanks!